# Quotient Topology, Munkres First Example

Tags: general-topology

Munkres defines a quotient maps using open sets (as is done [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map).) Then he comments that one could also formulate the definition using closed sets instead.

He considers the following example to show a function that is a quotient map, but not on the quotient map's restriction on a subset of the domain:

> Let $X$ be the subspace $[0.1] \cap [2,3]$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $Y$ be the subspace $[0.2]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. The map $p:X \rightarrow Y$ defined by
>   $$
>   p(x) =
>   \begin{cases}
>                x & x \in [0,1] \\
>   x-1 & x \in [2,3]
>   \end{cases}
>  $$
>   is readily seen to be surjective, continuous, and closed. Hence it is a quotient map. Now consider $[0,1) \cup [2,3] = A \subset X$, then the map $p|_A: A \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and surjective but not a quotient map. To see this, $[2,3]$ is open in $A$ and is saturated with respect to $p|_A$, but its image is not open in $Y$.

I see that this is true, but isn't $[2,3] \subset A$ also closed so that the image is closed in $X$. As far as I can see, $p|_A$ can be a closed map - isn't this true?

Comment: I would say $p$ is objective rather than subjective. On a more serious note, I'm confused by what you are asking.

Comment: whatever do you mean? :-)

Comment: where do you get lost? I'm basically saying, I see why $p|_A$ is not an open map. But I think its a closed map - therefore a quotient map. I "argued" this by citing one example. So I guess I'm fishing for a counter example: one that's closed in domain but not in range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p\mid_A$ is not a closed map. $[0,1)$ is closed in $A$ but $p|_A([0,1)) = [0,1)$ is not closed in $Y$.